# How to conditionally replace a key using dict comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary

```
d={'user': 'bala', 'password': 'pass', 'filetype': 'as-parquetfile'}
```

all keys are to be prefixed with `--` except `filetype` which should be replaced with `--` to get

```
{'--user': 'bala', '--password': 'pass', '--': 'as-parquetfile'}
```

If I do the below I get syntax error.

```
{'--'+k:v if k!='filetype' else '--':v for (k,v) in d.items()}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `key: value` part of the dict comprehension is no expression, so you can't use the ternary operator with it directly. What you can do is this:

```
{('--'+k if k!='filetype' else '--'): v for (k,v) in d.items()}
```

Comment: @pault You'd think so, but look at the requirement in the question.

Answer (score 2):

A dirty way I like to use:

```
d = {'user': 'bala', 'password': 'pass', 'filetype': 'as-parquetfile'}
d = {"--" + (k, "")[k=="filetype"]: v for k, v in d.items()}
d
>>> {'--': 'as-parquetfile', '--password': 'pass', '--user': 'bala'}
```

Comment: using True and False as index values for tuple is smart, however it is less readable